# How can I update itemname column using user id in table AuthAssignment Yii Framework

Tags: yii, rbac

I use auth manager (RBAC) in Yii Framework and I have a problem.
I want to update column itemname using user id in table AuthAssignment .
I can insert to database with this code:`Yii::app()->authManager->assign($model->role,$model->id);`
but ı don't know how can I update this data in table AuthAssignment .

Comment: just you need to generate CRUD of `AuthAssignment` and model and controller. Than using `update` action update data.

Comment: Your comment is not clear please update the answer if you want show your code. and format the code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no update action provided for AuthAssignment. For updating column itemname, you should first 'revoke' your item from given RBAC GUI, then 'assign' your updated item.

Let me know if you face further query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is not update method in auth manager(RBAC).So we must use revoke method for delete and assign method for insert. I use following code in Usercontroller

```
public function assignRole($role,$id) { 
    $auth = Yii::app()->authManager;
    $items = $auth->getRoles($id);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $auth->revoke($item->name, $id);
    } 
    // assign new role to the user 
    $auth->assign($role, $id);
    $auth->save();
}
```

Then I call following code for insert and update role to table

```
$this->assignRole($model->role,$model->id);
```